# C++ Visual Studio GUI does not show changes immediately

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, clr

I want to write a function to let labels in the GUI fade in. I use a for loop. Each step in that loop i set the color values of that label higher. After each step i have a time delay of 200 milliseconds.

The following code works, except that the changes in label-color are only visible after the loop is done.

````
```
void fade(System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        label->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(0, (i + 1) * 20, 0);
        Sleep(200); // milliseconds
    }
}
```
````

Is there a way to force the GUI to show changes immediately?
Or is there another way to let labels fade in?

Comment: How would you expect the colour of the label to change when you are stuck in your `for` loop setting values and sleeping and not returning to the eventloop? While you are sleeping your program does *nothing* - it doesn't magically respond to things you did before going to sleep (how would it?). One way to do what you want is to use a timer to trigger a call to a function that updates the colour as needed, then returns to the main event loop, ready to be triggered again some time later - and there are other ways as well

Comment: The main thread of your program can sleep or it can repaint these labels, it can't do both at the same time.  A big reason to never use Sleep().  A workaround is force a repaint, add label->Update();  Two seconds is rather long, make it better with a Timer.

Answer (score 2):

`label->Update();` did the trick. Thank you very much Hans.

```
void fade(System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                label->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(0, (i + 1) * 2, 0);
                Sleep(1); // milliseconds
                label->Update();
            }
        }
```